# ASP .NET Core application can't find bootstrap 5 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

Can't find classes from bootstrap after installing it.
Here's how I've added it to my project:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PROJECTNAME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap-utilities.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: is lib folder in webroot?

Comment: yes it is @daremachine

Comment: Is there any error message in the console window(press f12 in the browser)? And did you mean that the project can't find `bootstrap-5.1.3-dist`? According to the code snippet, it seems that you provided the _Layout.cshtml file in the Views/Shared folder, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is my test result, and my file's downloading from website and copied to the folder, but not installed through visual studio.

[image]